# Find a temperature from enthalpy

Tags: physics, curated-data

I would like to find a temperature by knowing the enthalpy, is this possible? 
This is what i've tried so far:

```
V1 = 150;
V2 = 4;
T1 = 15 + 273;

Enthalpy

h[T_] := QuantityMagnitude[
      ThermodynamicData["Air", 
       "Enthalpy", {"Temperature" -> Quantity[T, "Kelvins"]}]]

h1 = h[T1]


sol = Solve[h1 + V1^2/2 == h2 + V2^2/2]

{{h2 -> 425466.}}

FindRoot[h[T2] == h2 /. sol, {T2, 300}]

During evaluation of ThermodynamicData::quant: T2 is not a real number.

During evaluation of FindRoot::jsing: Encountered a singular Jacobian at the point {T2} = {300.}. Try perturbing the initial point(s).

{T2 -> 300.}
```

Comment: Are you trying to do something like solve the Clapeyron equation?

Comment: I am trying to find the temperature of air after it has went through a diffuser.

Comment: In the definition of `h`, restrict the arguments of `h` to numeric values, i.e., `h[T_?NumericQ] := ...`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help Bob!

Answer (score 2):

*Mathematica* is missing enthalpy data below 60K. Also evaluating the `ThermodynamicData` inside the `Solve` is slow. Try this:

```
enthalpy[t_?NumericQ] := 
 QuantityMagnitude[
  QuantityMagnitude[
   ThermodynamicData["Air", 
    "Enthalpy", {"Temperature" -> Quantity[t, "Kelvins"]}]]]
h2 = With[{V1 = 150, V2 = 4, T1 = 15 + 273}, 
  x /. Last@
    NMinimize[{((enthalpy[T1] + V1^2/2) - (x + V2^2/2))^2, x > 60}, x,
      MaxIterations -> 5]]
NMinimize[{(enthalpy[t] - h2)^2 , t > 60}, t, MaxIterations -> 5]
```

It's still a bit slow, and will be even slower with more iterations, but I get 299.173K.

Answer (score 1):

I would explicitly state the reference pressure (assuming 1 Bar).  Here is an alternative way:

```
Clear[h]
h[t_?NumericQ] := 
 QuantityMagnitude@
  ThermodynamicData["Air", 
   "Enthalpy", {"Pressure" -> Quantity[1, "Bars"], 
    "Temperature" -> Quantity[t, "Kelvins"]}]
V1 = 150;
V2 = 4;
T1 = 15 + 273;
h1 = h[T1];
sol = First@Solve[h1 + V1^2/2 == h2 + V2^2/2, h2];
t /. FindRoot[h[t] == h2 /. sol, {t, 273}]
(* 299.173 *)
```

Comment: Does the trick, much faster than mine.